# Commutator of finite global dimension algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A=KQ/I$ be a finite dimensional quiver algebra of finite global dimension.
Is it true that the dimension of $A/[A,A]$ is equal to the number of simples of $A$?
Here $[A,A]$ is the vector space generated by all elements of the form $ab-ba$.

Note that it is known that in general for such $A$ that the dimension of $A/([A,A]+rad(A))$ is equal to the number of simple $A$-modules. Thus the question should be equivalent to asking whether we have $rad(A) \subseteq [A,A]$ in case $A$ has finite global dimension.

Comment: I am maybe missing something, but what if your quiver has one vertex, and your algebra $A$ is the algebra of polynomials? What does your suggested result want to say then?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko A quiver algebra is finite dimensional for me. I add that assumption, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. See the result of Section 2.5 of a wonderful paper of Bernhard Keller :

https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/ilc.pdf

(and the references therein).